# Custom Nav Walker Displaying Values in Sub Menu

Tags: theme-development, menus, themes, sub-menu

I'm trying to display Submenu links within a Custom Tailwindcss / Vue component that I added within the Nav Walker.

[Menu Issues](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RCYBC.jpg)

header.php

```
    <nav class="flex items-center justify-between flex-wrap bg-teal-500 p-6">
<div class="flex items-center flex-shrink-0 text-white mr-6">
    <svg class="fill-current h-8 w-8 mr-2" width="54" height="54" viewBox="0 0 54 54" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path d="M13.5 22.1c1.8-7.2 6.3-10.8 13.5-10.8 10.8 0 12.15 8.1 17.55 9.45 3.6.9 6.75-.45 9.45-4.05-1.8 7.2-6.3 10.8-13.5 10.8-10.8 0-12.15-8.1-17.55-9.45-3.6-.9-6.75.45-9.45 4.05zM0 38.3c1.8-7.2 6.3-10.8 13.5-10.8 10.8 0 12.15 8.1 17.55 9.45 3.6.9 6.75-.45 9.45-4.05-1.8 7.2-6.3 10.8-13.5 10.8-10.8 0-12.15-8.1-17.55-9.45-3.6-.9-6.75.45-9.45 4.05z"/></svg>
    <span class="font-semibold text-xl tracking-tight">Tailwind CSS</span>
</div>
<div class="block lg:hidden">
    <button class="flex items-center px-3 py-2 border rounded text-teal-200 border-teal-400 hover:text-white hover:border-white">
    <svg class="fill-current h-3 w-3" viewBox="0 0 20 20" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><title>Menu</title><path d="M0 3h20v2H0V3zm0 6h20v2H0V9zm0 6h20v2H0v-2z"/></svg>
    </button>
</div>
<div class="w-full block flex-grow lg:flex lg:items-center lg:w-auto">
    <div class="text-sm lg:flex-grow">
        <?php
            wp_nav_menu(array (
                'theme_location' => 'Primary',
                'menu_id'        => 'Primary',
                'menu_class'     => 'Primary',
                'walker' => new Clean_Walker_Nav
            ));
        ?>
    </div>
    <div>
    <a href="#" class="inline-block text-sm px-4 py-2 leading-none border rounded text-white border-white hover:border-transparent hover:text-teal-500 hover:bg-white mt-4 lg:mt-0">Download</a>
    </div>
</div>
</nav>
```

inc/Clean_Walker_Nav.php

```
    class Clean_Walker_Nav extends Walker_Nav_Menu {
    /**
     * Filter used to remove built in WordPress-generated classes
     * @param  mixed $var The array item to verify
     * @return boolean      Whether or not the item matches the filter
     */
    function filter_builtin_classes( $var ) {
        return ( FALSE === strpos( $var, 'item' ) ) ? $var : '';
    }
    function start_lvl( &$output, $depth = 0, $args = array() ) {
        $indent = str_repeat("\t", $depth);
        $output .= "<div class='flex items-center'>";
        $output .= "<dropdown-link>";
        $output .= "<span slot='link' class='appearance-none flex items-center inline-block text-white font-medium'>";
        $output .= "<span class='mr-1'>$indent</span>";
        $output .= "<svg class='h-4 w-4' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' viewBox='0 0 20 20'>";
        $output .= "<path d='M9.293 12.95l.707.707L15.657 8l-1.414-1.414L10 10.828 5.757 6.586 4.343 8z' />";
        $output .= "</svg>";
        $output .= "</span>";
        $output .= "<div slot='dropdown' class='bg-white shadow rounded border overflow-hidden'>";
        $output .= "\n$indent<ul>\n";
        $output .= "</div>";
        $output .= "</dropdown-link>";
        $output .= "</div>";
    }
    function start_el( &$output, $item, $depth = 0, $args = array(), $id = 0 ) {
        $indent = ( $depth ) ? str_repeat( "\t", $depth ) : '';
        $class_names = $value = '';
        $unfiltered_classes = empty( $item->classes ) ? array() : (array) $item->classes;
        $classes = array_filter( $unfiltered_classes, array( $this, 'filter_builtin_classes' ) );
        if ( preg_grep("/^current/", $unfiltered_classes) ) {
            $classes[] = 'active';
        }
        $class_names = join( ' ', apply_filters( 'nav_menu_css_class', array_filter( $classes ), $item, $args ) );
        $class_names = $class_names ? ' class="' . esc_attr( $class_names ) . '"' : '';
        $id = apply_filters( 'nav_menu_item_id', 'menu-item-'. $item->ID, $item, $args );
        $id = $id ? ' id="' . esc_attr( $id ) . '"' : '';
        $output .= $indent . '<li' . $value . $class_names .'>';
        $atts = array();
        $atts['title']  = ! empty( $item->attr_title ) ? $item->attr_title : '';
        $atts['target'] = ! empty( $item->target )     ? $item->target     : '';
        $atts['rel']    = ! empty( $item->xfn )        ? $item->xfn        : '';
        $atts['href']   = ! empty( $item->url )        ? $item->url        : '';
        $atts = apply_filters( 'nav_menu_link_attributes', $atts, $item, $args );
        $attributes = '';
        foreach ( $atts as $attr => $value ) {
            if ( ! empty( $value ) ) {
                $value = ( 'href' === $attr ) ? esc_url( $value ) : esc_attr( $value );
                $attributes .= ' ' . $attr . '="' . $value . '"';
            }
        }
        $item_output = $args->before;
        $item_output .= '<a'. $attributes .'>';
        $item_output .= $args->link_before . apply_filters( 'the_title', $item->title, $item->ID ) . $args->link_after;
        $item_output .= '</a>';
        $item_output .= $args->after;
        $output .= apply_filters( 'walker_nav_menu_start_el', $item_output, $item, $depth, $args );
    }
}
```

**Update**

I've Managed to sort this All I needed todo was remove these lines.

```
        $output .= "</div>";
        $output .= "</dropdown-link>";
        $output .= "</div>";
```

Comment: And what’s the problem? What’s not working?

Comment: @JacobPeattie Thanks for commenting, what i'm trying todo is get the submenu to be looped out in the section. At the minute the sub-menu li items are not going into the ul.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've managed to sort this All I needed to do was remove these lines.

```
    $output .= "</div>";
    $output .= "</dropdown-link>";
    $output .= "</div>";
```